# timezone coversion issue in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to covert timezone from EST to IST in intellij IDEA, SO after conversion I am getting difference of 10 hr 30 min but when I am running same program with eclipse I am getting difference of 9 hr 30 min which is correct, regarding time difference you can check on google.

please refer the below code

```html
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Date dateValue = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-09-15 05:00:00.000 EST");
        System.out.println(dateValue);
```

Output:

```html
Correct value -  Tue Sep 15 14:30:00 IST 2015
Wrong value -    Tue Sep 15 15:30:00 IST 2015
```

Please suggest reason behind this.

Comment: What *exactly* are you expecting "EST" to mean? (It's not a time zone - it's an abbreviation which is used for Eastern Time for *half* the time.) And what result are you getting? Basically, we need to know whether you expect "EST" to mean "Eastern Time" (UTC-4 at the moment) or "Eastern Standard Time"  (UTC-5).

Comment: Hi Jon, i added the output

Comment: Yes, but you haven't clarified what you expect "EST" to mean. I suspect you're using two different versions of Java in the two IDEs, and they're treating this differently. Basically, using the abbreviations instead of time zone IDs is a really bad idea.

Comment: And your are not defining any timezone or offset part in your date format. So your programm expects the given input string as in EST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you actually want a time zone for Eastern Time, e.g. America/New_York. After all, Eastern Time wasn't observing EST on September 15 - it was observing EDT (at least, anywhere that observes daylight savings, which most of Eastern Time does as far as I'm aware).

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Date dateValue = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-09-15 05:00:00.000");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(dateValue));
```

This gives output of 2015-09-15 09:00:00, showing that America/New_York is indeed 4 hours behind UTC at the moment (and hence 9.5 hours behind India).

Now that's assuming you know that you really want it to be in Eastern time - which is why I removed the " EST" suffix from the string you're parsing. If you *actually* want to get the value from the string, you'll need to be very careful, given that those abbreviations are ambiguous - and in this case, apparently misapplied.

Comment: very help full - Thanks Jon :)